# $.extend property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Recently discovered $.extend and applied it on my code:

```
var chartFactory = function(options) {
    this.defaults = {
        type: "line",
        width: "800",
        height: "500",
        heightScale: {
            domain: ["0", "250"],
            range: ["300", "0"]
        },
        widthScale: {
            domain: ["0", "250"],
            range: ["0", "900"]
        },
        Yaxis: {
            ticks: ["5"],
            scale: "heightScale",
            orient: "left"
        },
        Xaxis: {
            ticks: ["10"],
            scale: "widthScale",
            orient: "bottom"
        }
    };
    $.extend(this.options, options, this.defaults);
};
```

I have this **chartFactory** class where **lineChart** is an object of it.

**EDIT:** Am trying to merge the contents of the object values with the default values such that the values of the new object that has been made is retained and the resultant should be on the new object.

```
var lineChart = new chartFactory({
    type: "line",
    Xaxis: {
        ticks: ["20"],
        scale: "widthScale",
        orient: "bottom"
    }
});
```

So basically when i consoled lineChart(console.log(lineChart),this is what came up:
[image]

The **lineChart.Xaxis.ticks** should have been "20".

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually create `this.options` first, then merge the other two objects into that object, passing `this.defaults` first, then `options`, as the latter will overwrite properties in the former

```
var chartFactory = function(options) {
    this.defaults = {
        type: "line",
        width: "800",
        height: "500",
        heightScale: {
            domain: ["0", "250"],
            range: ["300", "0"]
        },
        widthScale: {
            domain: ["0", "250"],
            range: ["0", "900"]
        },
        Yaxis: {
            ticks: ["5"],
            scale: "heightScale",
            orient: "left"
        },
        Xaxis: {
            ticks: ["10"],
            scale: "widthScale",
            orient: "bottom"
        }
    };
    this.options = {};
    $.extend(this.options, this.defaults, options);
};

var lineChart = new chartFactory({
    type: "line",
    Xaxis: {
        ticks: ["20"],
        scale: "widthScale",
        orient: "bottom"
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/t5HpX/1/)

Comment: $.extend(this.defaults, this.options, {}, options);

This 1 worked...
Though an undefined does come after the object in the console.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you mean the answer provided by @dfsq worked, but this didn't, you should ask him to undelete it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you just want to overwrite `this.defaults`, all you need is `$.extend(this.defaults, options)`, no empty object or non existing `this.options` ?

Comment: Yup,thats what i meant.
Both your answer and @76484 answer produced the same original result.

Comment: I think you're confused, my answer produces an instance with `this.defaults` staying unchanged, and creating a new `this.options` with the options argument added to the defaults, wasn't that what you were asking for ?

Comment: This answer works! And this is better answer, that's why I deleted mine and upvoted this one. The benefit of this answer that this code sets own property `this.options`, mine didn't.

Comment: @dfsq - I just assumed that was the question as the code in the question is `$.extend(this.options, {}, options, this.defaults);`, and `this.options` wasn't defined, and why would you stick an empty object in there ?

Comment: @adeneo I also think so.

Comment: @adeneo i upvoted ur comment,that's wot am aiming for. 
And ignore the empty object, i was trying out various stuff.
But when i still console the lineChart object,it returns with  lineChart.Xaxis.ticks 10 where it should have been "20".

Comment: Erm.. should i create a fiddle?
I have some extra code in there.. that's why i didnt bother to create the fiddle.

Comment: @Nevin Madhukar K: If the properties of defaults are to be overwritten by options then defaults needs to come before options in the .extend call.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK - But you're looking at the `defaults` property, open my fiddle in the answer and look in the console, there is also an `options` property, as in `this.options`, and that's where you'll find the updated `Xaxis`.

Comment: @adeneo i think i gave the wrong description,sorry.
Erm can u check the edit?

Comment: @adeneo To get lineChart.Xaxis.ticks=20?? That's what i need.

Comment: @adeneo I got the answer on lineChart.options.. thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Return your created object:

```
var chartFactory = function(options) {
    /* define this.defaults */
    return $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   var settings = $.extend({
            readonly   : 'true', // true for static rating only and false for the clickable star.
            score      : '0',      // total score of item 
            userscore  : '0',      // ratedby user 
            count      : '',     // rating count means no of user rated   
            size       : 'medium',  // size if star large or medium currently no option for small
            click      : function(){}   /// default function for click
        }, options);
```

**Just like this you need to pass value into {},**